# Language learning speech recognition tools

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition

I would like to write a program in C# that includes limited vocabulary speech recognition of languages such as Finnish or Polish. Microsoft's Speech SDK works great for English but can it support other languages like those? If not, what other (hopefully affordable) software tools are available?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Microsoft Server Speech Platform 10.2. It supports both STT and TTS.
For 26 Languages, including Finnish and Polish!

Here's a link that will get you started.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/TTSandSR.aspx

A bit late post, sorry for that.