# Language learning program, word recognition and comparing

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, similarity, speech-to-text

I'm trying to create polish/english language learning program.

I'm using C#, and ideally would like to support Windows XP, Vista and (obviously) newer versions.

At the beginning, computer selects some random polish/english word, and "says" it. Program user is then expected to say the same word, but in another language, and program evaluates his correctness. If user said correct word, he is granted a point, otherwise he loses a point.

My first idea was to use speech-to-text library (like System.Speech), but it turns out that
 polish language is not very well supported
 - speech-to-text is (afaik) not optimized for comparing words

Is there a better way to do it?
Do you know about any library that can do such thing? (Ideally managed library, but im ok with creating my own C# wrapper around unmanaged code).
Is there a name for the thing i want to achieve? (comparing spoken words)
Should I stick to speech-to-text libraries or find another algorithm?

I really tried to google solution, but i wasn't sure after which keyword should i search for. Best i could find was this thread: [Language learning speech recognition tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051222/language-learning-speech-recognition-tools). Solution presented there kind of works for me, but is problematic to deploy (i want a standalone application, with minimum installation) and testing 'correctness' of word that way is a bit weird (i am only 'recognising' single word).

Any help would be really appreciated. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read about [speech recognition using neural network](http://speech.bme.ogi.edu/tutordemos/nnet_recog/recog.html) if you intend to do some work in this area.